# Basic Loop/Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am supposed to write a program that displays numbers from 100 to 200, ten per line, that are divisible by 5 or 6 but NOT both. This is my code so far. I know it's a basic problem so can you tell me the basic code that I'm missing instead of the "shortcut" steps. Any help is appreciated!

```
    def main():
      while (num >= 100) and (num <= 200):
      for (num % 5 == 0) or (num % 6 == 0)
        print (num)

    main()
```

Comment: This has clear Syntax errors, OP. That `for` loop is wrong and no `:` follows it, for example (I'm guessing the indentation is due to copy/paste). Instead of posting a question which isn't even valid, I'd suggest you take a look at one of the many Python Tutorials out there.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would go about it. I would recommend using a for loop over a while loop if you know the range you need. You are less likely to get into an endless loop. The reason for the n variable is since you said you needed 10 numbers per line. The n variable will track how many correct numbers you find so that you know when you have ten results and can use a normal print statement which automatically includes a newline. The second print statement will not add a newline.

```
n = 0
for i in range(100,201):
    if (i%5 == 0 or i%6 == 0) and not (i%5 == 0 and i%6 == 0):
        n += 1
        if n%10 == 0:
            print(i)
        else:            
            print(str(i) + ", ", end="")
```

Comment: Why should he go about this? I'm not questioning the validity of your answer, rather, I urge you to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

You should init every variable using in the code
While (condition) will break when the condition false. Since your condition depends on num, but num is never changed in your code, infinity loop will happen. You need to add `num = num + 1` at the end of your loop block.
It's supposed to use if not for for each iterator here. And the condition you used for your problem is wrong to.

Should be like this:

```
def main():
    num = 100
    while (num >= 100) and (num <= 200):
        if ((num % 5 == 0) or (num % 6 == 0)) and (num % 30 != 0):
            print (num)
        num = num + 1
main()
```